# JavaSE com CDI e JPA - Erro WELD-001303

Tags: java, jpa, cdi

Estou estudando JPA e CDI em uma aplicação Java SE. Quando vou criar o `EntityManagerFactory` me deparo com o erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
```

EntityMangerFactory:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class EntityManagerProducer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "banco")
    private EntityManagerFactory factory;

    @RequestScoped
    @Produces
    public EntityManager createEntityManager() {
        return factory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void closeEntityManager(@Disposes EntityManager manager) {
        if (manager.isOpen()) {
            manager.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Classe Main:

```
public class Main {

    @Inject
    UserDao userDao;

    public void main(@Observes ContainerInitialized event, @Parameters List<String> params) {

        User u = new User();

        u.setName("usuario");
        u.setCpf("12345678911");
        u.setEmail("cxxxx@sss.com.br");
        u.setLastName("rocha");
        u.setPassword("12345679");

        userDao.salvar(u);
    }
}
```

Alterei o `EntityManagerProducer`, dessa forma ele funciona, mas sem os escopos.
É o correto ?

```
public class EntityManagerProducer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Produces
    public EntityManager createEntityManager() {
        return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("white-dragon").createEntityManager();
    }

    public void closeEntityManager(@Disposes EntityManager manager) {
        if (manager.isOpen()) {
            manager.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Como você está iniciando o *container* no *main* (o `main(String[] args)`)? Existe o `beans.xml` na sua aplicação?

Comment: @BrunoCésar, Editei a questão e inseri o main. Sim, existe o beans.xml com ```bean-discovery-mode="all"```.

Comment: Este você já havia incluído. Como não tem o *main* (`main(String[] args)`), provavelmente está iniciando sua aplicação com o `StartMain`, é isso?

Comment: É isso mesmo, iniciar pelo StartMain. Desculpe, acabei não entendendo bem a pergunta.

Comment: Certo. Para injetar um `EMF` você precisa estar produzindo ele, assim como produz a `EM`. Como você está fazendo isto? Se não está, este é o motivo do erro. Então, crie um *producer* para `EMF` também, ou altere o seu `createEntityManager` para algo como isto: `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("banco").createEntityManager();`

Comment: Eu fiz dessa forma
    ```public EntityManager createEntityManager() {
        return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("banco").createEntityManager();
    }``` O mesmo erro continua, mas eu tirei a anotação @RequestScoped e funcionou normalmente.
Será que por ser uma aplicação SE, não é necessário os escopos de Request, Application etc.. ?

Comment: Vi sua atualização. Desta forma você pode usar `@RequestScoped` em `createEntityManager`, que é o usual. Testou isso?

Comment: Testei sim, e também não funciona, a exceção só não é lançada sem as duas annotations. Mas, fiz um teste com @Dependent (é o escopo padrão, não ?) e funcionou normalmente.

Comment: Sim, nem precisa de `@Dependent`, exatamente por ser padrão. Olhando a documentação, em ambiente `JavaSE` a `@RequestedScoped`  não funciona mesmo em determinados casos.

Comment: Realmente. Acabei de olhar na documentação, e só funcionam os escopos ```@Application, @Dependent, @Singleton``` Que distração minha.

Comment: Wellington, marque sua resposta como a correta, pode ajudar outras pessoas :)

Comment: Vou marcar, mas o pelo que diz na mensagem, tenho que esperar até amanhã ahhahaha. 
Obrigado pela ajuda !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encontramos na documentação que apenas os escopos `@Application, @Dependent e @Singleton` são suportados em ambiente SE.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class EntityManagerProducer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Produces
    public EntityManager createEntityManager() {
        return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("banco").createEntityManager();
    }

    public void closeEntityManager(@Disposes EntityManager manager) {
        if (manager.isOpen()) {
            manager.close();
        }
    }
}
```